# Configure Windows logon script with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I want to make a powershell script that creates another powershell script that is always executed at userlogin from windows.

The purpose is that I would like to change the number of files taken at each user login.

My question how can I put a script via powershell and tell windows to run this script every time a user logs in.

I would appreciate an answer because I am really desperate.

Comment: Yes. And how can I create a logon script via powershell.

Comment: Depends on your needs. A quick Google search for something like, "*Task schedule at user logon to run powershell script*" should get you in the right direction. If you are having trouble with your code, come back and post it so we can assist in troubleshooting it